# The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. Flask

Tags: python, flask

So i am trying to implement flask `flask_classful`, i am following the basic application as described on http://flask-classful.teracy.org/ , i get the following error

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
> manually please check your spelling and try again.

This is the basic code that i am using in my handler.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_classful import FlaskView

# we'll make a list to hold some quotes for our app
quotes = [
    "A noble spirit embiggens the smallest man! ~ Jebediah Springfield",
    "If there is a way to do it better... find it. ~ Thomas Edison",
    "No one knows what he can do till he tries. ~ Publilius Syrus"
]

app = Flask(__name__)

class QuotesView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):
        return "<br>".join(quotes)

QuotesView.register(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. The site can be reached at [`http://localhost:5000/quotes/`](http://localhost:5000/quotes/).

Comment: @Detlef: could it be my virtual env causing this?

Comment: I can't imagine. I am using [python venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and it works. Has anything been printed on the command line?

Comment: Can you start the `flask shell` and then with `from app import app; app.url_map` show all valid url mappings? The following should appear. `Map([<Rule '/quotes/' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> QuotesView: index>, <Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> static>]) `

Comment: If I get this error, it's usually because the host name does not match